# Problem in distributing GDAL in stand alone application

Tags: qgis, gdal, python-3

I'm desperate with the distributing problem of gis packages each time. It is the third day that I'm desperately trying to make an .exe using Pyinstaller to a small application I developed using GDAL and PyQt5 with Python 3.7. 
I use Pycharm IDE with venv based on the qgis_ltr 3.4 Python as a project interpreter.

First to make the dev environment I had to run Pycharm with a batch that sets environments variables. Now that I want to make the install, I know I must reference GDAL somehow, after trying many alternatives ( installing gdal in a venv )  Nothing seems to work.

I get the exe file but that gives an error message not founding the GDAL module. 
Is there any simple way to correctly generate the .exe file?